# How do I control the internet access in a private network?

Tags: networking, internet

I'm administering a small private network and for legal purposes I need to do the following:

- Restrict the internet access to a few machines uniquely identified by a username and password
- Log the internet-traffic of every user and save the logs corresponding to the user

I was thinking about some kind of server which I plug between the Web and my users? Anyone able to give me a hint?

Comment: Given that you don't seem to know much about System Administration I would *highly recommend* a packaged solution, a device or software specifically meant for the type of situation you're in (quite a few compliance solutions exist, some are even quite cheap).

Comment: I'm not a network admin. But i am a theoretical physicist, so i reckon i can cope with the situation. Also i have the freedom to fiddle around a bit, and learn. No one is done any harm. But thx for the concern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proxy server.

Something like Squid on Linux, or a self-contained OS distribution that has it included.

Comment: Never configured a proxy-server. But if this is what im looking for, im trying this out. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a [**proxy server**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server).

[**Squid**](http://www.squid-cache.org/) will work on both [windows](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/BinaryPackages#Windows) and [linux](http://www.squid-cache.org/Download/).